# Vertically center link text in flexbox layout

Tags: css

I have a menu made up of 5 links. I need each link to be 33% of the available width with spacing between the links. The horizontal and vertical spacing must be the same.

Links must be the same height as the tallest link in there row, even though the length of the link text will vary per link. Ideally all links would be the same height but I doubt this is possible.

The link text is dynamic and will change. This for a responsive website so the page width will vary.

I cant change the HTML at all.

This is for a mobile only website so I dont need to worry about older browsers. I should be fine to use flexbox.

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#">
            <span>Link 1</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">
            <span>Link 2 has much longer text than the other links</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">
            <span>Link 3</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">
            <span>Link 4</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">
            <span>Link 5</span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

My code below works fine in Chrome. The only thing I still need to do is vertically center the link text (see the image below).

The align-items: center property looked promising however If I apply it to the ul then the lis' stop being the same height.

```
*, *:before, *:after {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box;
 }

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 50%;
  border: 2px solid black;
  margin: auto;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
  float: left;
  width: 32%;
  background: grey;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-bottom: 2%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

li:nth-of-type(2),
li:nth-of-type(5)
{
  margin-left: 2%;
  margin-right: 2%;
}

a {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: -10em;
  padding: 10em;
}
a {
  background: gold;
}
a:hover {
  background: green;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/CeiqK

[image]

Comment: Table? It looks like tabular data.

Comment: @bjb568 agree. Tabular data, use `<table>`. +1

Comment: It looks like a tabular data, but don't forget that it is a menu. `ul` tag is recommended for that purpose. Anyway looks that he can't change html code

Comment: Well, does it have rows and columns, or is it just arranged that way?

Comment: @bjb568 I think the second choice, but I am not sure at all

Comment: It is a menu. At wider widths the links will all sit in a row. This is for smaller screens (targeted with a media query).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this solution that I post here will be valid for you. Anyway, I changed your css a bit to get it:

```
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 50%;
  border: 2px solid black;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-size: 0;  /* this fix inline-block margins */
}

li {
  font-size: 14px;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 32%;
  min-height: 34px;
  background: grey;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-bottom: 2%;
}

a {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 100em;
  height: 34px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

**[Check it at codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Ahlvr)**

Creates this:

[image]

Comment: If you want to center vertically `li` elements, add `vertical-align: middle;` to `li` css rule

Comment: it's not such simple. The problem is the OP wants the `ul` to be a ***flex box***, That's why it's much harder to align the text vertically as the OP wants. As far as I know, when using flex-box, all the flex-items won't be able to use `display` style freely, hence we can't use `display:table-cell` as a trick to align the text  vertically.

Comment: I am not really familiarized with flex box, but I think that there is no need to use it to get his target. Anyway, I couldn't find another solution only with css

Comment: Ive updated your question with an screen shot of the codepen link. The links dont stay as tall as the tallest in theyre row, and I need them too.

Comment: Uhm, if you can't change the html I think there is no way to get same heights for all elements. Think that using a table you can get your target. Or javascript..